# Problem with undo-tree-visualizer keybindings

Tags: key-bindings, evil, use-package, undo-tree-mode

**What I want**

I use *general*, *use-package* and *evil*. I want to use evil keybindings in **undo-tree-visualizer-mode** to jump between nodes and branches using "j", "k", "h", "l" keys in normal state.

**My evil and general config**

```
(use-package evil
  :init      ;; tweak evil's configuration before loading it
  (setq evil-want-integration t) ;; This is optional since it's already set to t by default.
  (setq evil-want-keybinding nil)
  (setq evil-vsplit-window-right t)
  (setq evil-split-window-below t)
  (setq evil-want-C-u-scroll t)
  (setq evil-want-C-i-jump nil)
  (setq evil-respect-visual-line-mode t)
  (setq evil-undo-system 'undo-tree)
  (evil-mode))

(use-package general
  :diminish
  :config
  (general-evil-setup)
```

**What I have tried**

1. Defining keybindings with evil

```
(with-eval-after-load 'evil-maps
(evil-define-key 'normal undo-tree-visualizer-mode-map (kbd "k") 'undo-tree-visulize-undo)
(evil-define-key 'normal undo-tree-visualizer-mode-map (kbd "j") 'undo-tree-visulize-redo)
(evil-define-key 'normal undo-tree-visualizer-mode-map (kbd "h") 'undo-tree-visulize-switch-branch-left)
(evil-define-key 'normal undo-tree-visualizer-mode-map (kbd "l") 'undo-tree-visulize-switch-branch-right)
```

2. use-packege :bind

```
(use-package undo-tree
  :bind(:map undo-tree-visualizer-mode-map
             ("k" . undo-tree-visualize-undo)
             ("j" . undo-tree-visualize-redo)
             ("h" . undo-tree-visualize-switch-branch-left)
             ("l" . undo-tree-visualize-switch-branch-right))
  :init
  (global-undo-tree-mode 1))
```

I don't get any errors with both of these approaches.
I did restart emacs after changing my config, but the issue still persisted.

**What I think is happening**

undo-tree-visualizer-mode is a minor mode with its own local keymap. This local mode-map has already defined keys. When invoking undo-tree-visualizer-mode it opens new buffer with evil integration, but my keybidings don't work here. Local keybindings set for this mode should take precedence over global keybindings. I feel like I'm doing something wrong with remapping / overriding existing keybindings.

Will greatly appreciate help in understanding what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Personally, I open `special-mode` buffers in `motion-state` (as 'special-mode` is read-only anyway), as follows `(add-to-list 'evil-motion-state-modes 'special-mode)
`. Then the undo tree visualizer is working fine with evil without doing any extra configuration.

Comment: `(use-package undo-tree
    :init
    (global-undo-tree-mode 1)
    :config
    (add-hook 'udno-tree-visualizer-hook
              (lambda()
              (add-to-list 'evil-previous-visual-line 'undo-tree-visualize-redo))))`
This is what I tried. No errors but also no desired outcome. Most likely, I didn't understand how to apply what you wrote.

Comment: Just add this line to your config `(add-to-list 'evil-motion-state-modes 'special-mode)`.